# Prevent app to uninstall like system app android

Tags: android, root, uninstallation, root-access

We are developing one app that will be pre-installed on device manufacture time. seems like a bloatware app.

we want to prevent our app to uninstall by user like Contacts and other pre-installed app.

i searched a lot on google. but getting the same technique like using device rooting.

i also tried by using **[this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en)** app. but when i am clicking on any app to move to "System/apps", it gives me message

> "/system/app mover has been granted superuser permission"

and then i am getting Error i.e

> "Error: cp: applet not found"

with **Ok** Option.

So i tried by using "Es File Explorer" to move app from "data/app/" to "System/app/" its also moving app to "System/app" but when i am going through App Manager, it allow me to "Uninstall". but i want to disable "Uninstall button" like other pre-installed app act.

i tried the same method.

1. Rooted my device.
2. Moved my app from data/app/ to system/app/
3. set permission `rw- r-- r--` and reboot.

Still i am able to uninstall my app. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: There is many apps available in playstore to convert user app to system app in rooted device.Just search. I tried this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.systemappmover&hl=en and successfully moved app.

Comment: i tried by using this app too. but when i am clicking on any app to move to "System/apps", it gives me message "/system/app mover has been granted superuser permission" and then i am getting Error i.e "Error: cp: applet not found" with Ok Option. so i tried by using "Es File Explorer" to move app from "data/apps" to "system/apps/" its also moving app to "System/apps" but when i am going through App Manager, it allow me to "Uninstall". but i want to disable "Uninstall button" like other pre-installed app act.

Comment: Did you try to move your app to /system/app instead of /system/apps?

Comment: Have you tried converting any other apps like facebook, whatsapp?? Sorry I can't really help here with that that error.

Comment: Error message says that `cp` command could not be found. Please install BusyBox and try again.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox

Comment: First remove all the instances of app. Uninstall the app from the device & use adb command i.e adb push <source_path> <destination_path> where destination_path will be /system/priv-app/ and then reboot the device

Comment: Steps To make system App on root devices with super user permission:  1. mount our device for read/write permission 2. Copy your apk to sdcard 3. move your apk from sdcard to /stystem/priv-app/ 4. change chown command to system 5. change read write permission to full access. 6 reboot your device.